# How to change order of generated table columns EF Core 5?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I need to change an order of code first generated columns in EF Core. I have tried deleting database and re-creating it with `dotnet ef database update` command, but it keeps this weird order. Is there a way to fix an order without applying attributes?

[image]

Comment: Can you please show the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF Core 6 has this possibility https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/3469

```cs
builder.Property(x => x.Some)
  .HasColumnOrder(1);
```

Prior versions requires defining order via `ColumnAttribute`